# Magento trying to allocate excessive amounts of memory

Tags: php, magento, memory

I'm having an issue with my Magento 1.6.1.0 community edition store. It's attempting to allocate roughly half a gigabyte of memory every 15 seconds or so. Unfortunatly the error message isn't very helpful as you can see below:

```
[29-Mar-2012 07:36:38] PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 431187952 bytes) in Unknown on line 0
[29-Mar-2012 07:36:40] PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 244111344 bytes) in Unknown on line 0
[29-Mar-2012 07:36:54] PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 523921392 bytes) in Unknown on line 0
[29-Mar-2012 07:37:07] PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 534718448 bytes) in Unknown on line 0
```

I've spoken to my hosting about this and while they say that the memory limit of 128Mb is a little low for running a full magento store (we intend on upgrading to a more generous package when it's live) these errors suggest something is wrong with Magento rather than the hosting since I'm fairly sure that this is not normal behaviour. I can't change my memory limit from 128Mb on this package.

It continues to happen around the clock even during times when I can be fairly certain nobody is accessing the site at all. This makes me wonder if it's to do with the cron jobs Magento runs.

Does anyone have any tips on how to help track down this issue? Or has anyone run into something similar before?

Comment: Honestly that doesn't sound like too much for Magento to be tying to allocate. It's a resource hog of the first order. You really can't run it in lower RAM environments like yours.

Comment: This error hasn't been there since we first installed though, I'm afraid I can't tell you when it started exactly since the log is truncated. Is there a way we can tell exactly which part of Magento is trying to allocate all this memory? The error message isn't very helpful at all.

Comment: Can you run it through a profiler like webgrind? This will show you your biggest resource hogs. https://github.com/jokkedk/webgrind

Answer (score 4):

before installing any kind of software you should overview system requirements:

http://www.magentocommerce.com/system-requirements

and Magento specifically states there

`Memory_limit no less than 256Mb (preferably 512)`

Comment: With all due respect though, I'm fairly certain that Magento isn't supposed to be allocating that much memory in one chunk, this doesn't look like Magento running out of memory from overuse where it tries to allocate a small amount of memory, this is trying to allocate up to 600Mb as one large chunk.

Comment: @MarkFl **I can't change my memory limit from 128Mb on this package.** This hosting provider is a waste of time. Given that they won't allow a change to the minimum memory that Magento requires (256M) they probably also have other issues that are causing a major problem with Magento. Your story is repeated so often on the Magento forms over on Magentocommerce that Anton's reply is pretty standard. First find a hosting provider that supports Magento and a lot of the problems go away. Refusal to heed this advice leaves you chasing Chimeras.

Comment: @Fiasco Labs Had I come here and posted:
`[29-Mar-2012 07:37:07] PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 536870912 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 534718448 bytes) in Unknown on line 0`
Would your response have been different? Magento still isn't supposed to be allocating half a gigabyte of memory at once.

Comment: @MarkFI, indeed Magento may not "supposed to be" allocating that much, but it certainly is. A generic Magento install on a 128Mb RAM host may work, but once you start adding in attributes, products, etc, that 128Mb is completely insufficient, as is 256Mb. On many of the sites I work on, Magento gets 1Gb of RAM and I still see white screens when trying to do something like Mage::log($_category,null,'cat.log');  Take the advice, put it on a better hosting package, preferably with a host that knows how to optimize for Magento.

Comment: Somewhere, that memory limitation would have come out and **yes** I would have given you the same response. Our benighted original developer had us on such a system, could not increase the memory and mysql crashed taking out a weeks worth of work on assigning categories. Since you are not being given the proper resources, you have no idea what other things between apache, php and mysql are misconfigured or given such low factory defaults in the attempt to **play nice** with your neighbors, such that Magento does really weird things.

Comment: Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 536870912 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 261904 bytes) in C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Config.php on line 621
solve this buddy i add 512  in php ini